# Using the -- operator in a while loop produces unexpected results

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

In this formula,

```
var x = 5; while(x--) { console.log(x) }
```

The output is

```
4
3
2
1
0
```

Why would `0` be output? On the fifth iteration, `x--` would be equal to `0` which is falsey, so the loop should not run.

On the same token, this returns `true`

```
var x = 1;
(x--) == true;
```

But this returns false

```
0 == true
```

Comment: Because the `--` happens *after* `x` is evaluated. Contrast with `--x`.

Comment: In fairness, most languages with similar operators work... well, similarly.

Comment: That's nothing to do with Javascript, that's how post-increment works in every language?

Comment: prefix and postfix behavior isn't a JavaScript oddity here

Comment: Heh.  You can't blame this one on JavaScript.  The post-decrement operator behaves the same way in C, C++, Java, and C#, and probably other languages in that family that I'm not thinking of right now.

Comment: "Damnit Javascript" would be suitable for a statement like `a = 1; (+[])-1-a--` ;)

Answer (score 6):

x-- evaluates first and then decrements the variable.
If you use --x instead, you would get what you expect.

Comment: Interesting, and it evaluates it before the block as well.